# Method of undetermined coefficients for the input functions associated with the unit step

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a second order non-homogeneous differential equation where $x(t)$ has $u(t)$, the unit step as a part. i.e. $ x(t)= f(t)u(t) $

I know how to 'guess' the particular solution for $ f(t)$ alone, but I'm not sure how it should be done when the unit step is appended.

Is there a standard method for guessing the particular solution in this scenario?

E.g.

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} t^2} + 2\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t}+2y = \sin(3t)u(t)
$$

Comment: and $u(t)$ is the unit step at what value of $t$?  (I assume it steps up at $t=0$, but I'm just making sure...)

Comment: yes, it's the standard step. 
u(t)=1 for all t>=0 and otherwise u(t)=0

Comment: Wait a second...  did you mean to mix the variables $x$ and $t$ in your example? (I think I misunderstood your question to start off with... `;)`)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry @anorton, it was a mistake. Both x and y are functions of t.